# Can't filter aggregation based on shingles field

Tags: elasticsearch

When applying wildcard filter on shingles field I'm still getting bucket keys that not match the filter...

```
"aggregations": {
    "test": {
      "filter": {
        "wildcard": {
          "name.shingles": {
            "value": "*red*"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "shingles": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name.shingles",
            "size": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Results (expectation is to have only first bucket as it contains "red"):

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "test" : {
      "doc_count" : 7,
      "shingles" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 57,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "turning red",
            "doc_count" : 3
          },
          {
            "key" : "aces of",
            "doc_count" : 2
          },
          {
            "key" : "aces of the",
            "doc_count" : 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include your index mapping and a sample of the data, without that it is not possible to answer your question.
Some pointers:
Is the "name.shingles" a "keyword" or "text". If its "text" your filter won't work, as the field will be analyzed?

Comment: It's a `text` with `fielddata: true`

Comment: Change to "keyword", should solve your problem. Please mark my answer as correct, if it does! Filters don't work predictably on analyzed fields. Fielddata doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: You can't make a field that uses shingles analyzer as a keyword and `fielddata` is the most important here to make it work for a multi-field.

Comment: Please include your index mapping, you haven't told me that you are using a shingles analyzer. I can't help you without seeing the entire index mapping. Thanks! And give me at least 3 example documents.